# Hibernate unable to save child objects using cascade all

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following two classes. Class 'Type' has a an object of class 'Content'.
I want to save all referenced objects of class 'Type' by using the hibernate.save() method. I have specified the cascade type as ALL in class 'Content'.

Following is the error i face:
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing.

Can someone please help me identify what the problem is?

```
public class Type {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "content_id")
    private Content content;
    }

    public class Content {
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "content", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Type type;
    }

    public class Test {
        public void createType() {
            Type type = new Type();
            Content content = someMethodToGetContent();
            type.setContent(content);
            save(type); 
        }

        public void save(Object domainObj) {
            getEntityManager().persist(domainObj);
            getEntityManager().flush();
        }
    }
```

**Stacktrace:**

> Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references
>   an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing: .content -> .Content  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:387)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:172)   at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:154)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:145)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:795)
>     ... 27 more
>   org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
>   commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transacti on marked as
>   rollbackOnly  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.persist(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as
>   rollbackOnly  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73)     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
>     ... 12 more

Comment: Where is the code trying to save? What does it save? What's the **complete** stack trace of the exception?

Comment: is there a transient variable in your class?

Comment: @JBNizet: Added code

Comment: @LKTN: No there isn't

Comment: @minion Your save isnt taking any parameter, and whats domainObj? Is that what you are passing.

Comment: @NickDiv Typo corrected

Comment: Can you post the logic on someMethodToGetContent(). I guess you are missing the below line in someMethodToGetContent(). method      content.setType(type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hibernate unable to save child objects using cascade all

The reason why this does not work has to do with the way you're trying to persit the entities.

- Let us see what the following code is doing:

  ```
  Type type = new Type();
  Content content = someMethodToGetContent();
  type.setContent(content);
  save(type);
  ```

You are telling the persistence provider you want to save `type` by calling `save(type)` and expecting `content` should also be saved to the database. But in the entity `Type` the `OneToOne` annotation is does not contain the `PERSIST` cascade option. So you have to tell the persistence provider to to pesist an instance of `Content` when an instance of `Type` is persisted by changing your `OneToOne` annotation as follows:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)    // modified
@JoinColumn(name = "content_id")
private Content content;
```

And because you defined to entities to have bi-directional relationship you should wire them as follows correctly:

```
Type type = new Type();
Content content = someMethodToGetContent();
content.setType(type);                       // modified
type.setContent(content);
save(type);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out what i missed out. I added the cascade option to the 'Type' class and the objects were persisted. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I have one more question. Lets say the above object 'Type' has 1-1 relationships with many objects 'A','B','C'. I want to make sure that whenever 'Type' is persisted 'A','B' and 'C' are too. But not the other way round i.e. when i persist 'A' i do not want 'Type' to be persisted. 
This should be achieved if i add the CASCADE option only in class 'Type' and not in class 'A','B','C'. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes. If `A` does not specify the cascade type `PERSIST` on its 1-1 relationship the persistence provider will not try to persist the referenced entity. But you should be aware of something: if the table corresponding to `A` is holding a foreign key to the table corresponding to `Type`  and if this column is marked `NOT NULL` you'll get database constraint violation error because the parent entity will not be persisted.

Comment: Okay. In my database design the foreign keys of A, B and C are all held in table 'Type'.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your createType() as below.

```
public void createType() {
Type type = new Type();
Content content = someMethodToGetContent();
content.setType();
type.setContent(content);
save(type); 
}
```

Comment: Sreenath: Thanks a bunch for you answer. As @ujulu pointed i added the cascade option in the 'Type' class and changed the createType method as you both mentioned and persisted Type object and it worked fine.